# Return text if 3 cells in a row are equal in another row

Tags: excel, find, lookup

I would like to ask if there is a way to return text if exactly 3 cells in a row are equal to another 3 cells in another row.

Example of how I want it to look like.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean: "I would like to ask if there is a way to return text if exactly 3 cells in a **row** are equal to another 3 cells in another row."

Comment: Yes, sorry for that! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,B:B,B1,C:C,C1)>1, "ERROR", "OK")
```

`COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,B:B,B1,C:C,C1)` counts the number of times a series of cells A1, B1 and C1 appear in the columns A, B and C.

If it's above 1 (there's more than one), put `ERROR`, else `OK`.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a new cell by using the CONCATENATE() function to join the three cells together. Then use formatting to highlight duplicates in the new column.

Comment: Good idea, but it could fail if: `1 23 45` is compared with `12 34 5`.

Comment: Well spotted! :-) I guess the OP could concatenate the leftmost cell, a hyphen, the central cell, another hyphen and then the rightmost cell.