# If multiple rows are equal but one row is different

Tags: excel

I followed the answer here [Return text if 3 cells in a row are equal in another row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20955830/return-text-if-3-cells-in-a-row-are-equal-in-another-row) to figure out how to select rows that contain equal values. However, I want to add an additional check to see if the value in column A is not equal to any of the rows that have the other equal values.

```
Chris   No  Base    Bulbasaur   No
Chris   No  Base    Bulbasaur   No
```

In this example, I would want it to return "OK" because even though Rows B, C, D, and E are equal, row A is equal so that's okay. Now in this next example:

```
Chris   No  Base    Bulbasaur   No
Tom     No  Base    Bulbasaur   No
```

I want it to return "Duplicate" because the names are different.

Here is my formula right now that needs the additional check:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,C:C,C2,D:D,D2,E:E,E2)>1, "Duplicate", "OK")
```

Comment: What do you mean additional check? What is wrong with your formula? When does it work? When does it not work?

Comment: What is the output if the names are the same but the other fields are not? Is this OK?

Comment: @urdearboy Not exactly. I want all cases of where all 5 columns are equal to show up as OK. I want it to show up as duplicate only when rows B through E are equal and row A is different. So the 2nd conditional statement has to somehow reference the row that contained rows B through E being identical

Comment: If the names are the same but the other fields are not I want that to display "OK"